# Store new user to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have bookshelf model with data in it.

```
bookshelf: id, book_id, user_id, is_read:false
```

And i need to pass/add every new user `id` into bookshelf `user_id` for all existed `book_id`'s

```
//user.rb
has_many :bookshelfs
has_many :books, through: :bookshelfs
```

```
//bookshelf.rb 
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :book
```

I using devise gem. What i need to write inside my regestrations_controller.rb?

```
def create
    super
    ... 
 end
```

Comment: Can you add some more information about your schema please?  Specifically, how bookshelf, book and user relate, and any join tables etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `after_create` hook inside your user model, this way, whenever new user is created you will add him to bookshelf.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  after_create :add_to_all_existing_books
  ...
  private

  def add_to_all_existing_books
    Book.where(is_read: false).each do |b|
      Bookshelf.create(book_id: b.id, user_id: self.id, is_read: false)
    end       
  end
end
```